# Create control conditionally - bindings

Tags: wpf, binding, interface

```
<Page>  
                <local:AControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=A}"/>
                <local:BControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=B}"/>
                <local:CControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=C}"/>
                <local:DControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=D}"/>
                <local:EControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=E}"/>
</Page>
```

And in parent page     `public InterfaceType SelectedItem { get; set; }`

Hello,
I have some controls which visibility depends on SelectedItem type, ToVisibilityConverter just change the visibility depending on ConverterParameter.
This example works, but of course if the item underlying in SelectedItem is changed, there are binding errors on the other controls which visibility is collapsed, that's obvious, because properties don't match. So my goal is to remove that binding errors - to do that I should do something that shouldn't create or update control if it is not of correct type. How to achieve it? How to handle these solutions? For example kind of injecting but how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an easy solution:

```
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=SendPushWindow,
                Path=DataContext.SelectedItem,
                Converter={StaticResource ToTemplateConverter}}">
```

And in converter just return that control :) Sorry for bothering